# How to grab links only from sitemap?

Tags: apify, crawlee

I want to grab links only from the sitemap with Crawlee and not grab links from pages found in the sitemap. The main problem is that it starts from a sitemap and then follows all links on the newly discovered page.
The expected workflow should be like this:

1. Pass sitemap URL
2. Find all links in the sitemap
3. Follow links from it
4. Scrape needed content
5. Exit when links from the sitemap are finished

I am using Playwright as an agent.